# Evaluating a sum $-\zeta'(2)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, closed-form

Is it possible to obtain any closed-form expression for the infinite sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n^{2}}$$ by Residue calculus?

My thought was to try to integrate $$f(z) =\frac{\pi\log(z)}{z^{2}\tan(\pi z)}$$ over the rectangle $R_{M}$ with vertices $(M+\frac{1}{2})(\pm 1 \pm i)$

Comment: It is possible to get a closed form solution...but its in term of the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant) $G$. We have $I = -\frac{\pi^2}{6}(\gamma + \log(2\pi) - 12 \log(G))$

Comment: @Winther I'd rather write $A$ in terms of $-\zeta'(2)$ if I was asked the closed form of $A$ :-) although its just my opinion.

Comment: @r9m Agreed. It's a messy constant, its not very nice imo.

Comment: http://mathhelpboards.com/challenge-questions-puzzles-28/euler-maclaurin-summation-formula-riemann-zeta-function-7702.html

One can then relate $\zeta'(-1)$ and $\zeta'(2)$ via the Riemann zeta functional equation.

Comment: You would need to deform the rectangle around the branch cut for the logarithm.