# Integration of function having logarithmic and exponential terms

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> Find the value of $\displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x\ln x}{1+e^x}dx$

What I tried.
$$I = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x\ln x}{1+e^x}dx = \int^{\infty}_{0}x\ln x\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}dx$$
By parts 
$$I =-x\ln x\ln |1+e^{-x}|\bigg|^{\infty}_{0}+\int^{\infty}_{0}(1+\ln x)\ln|1+e^{-x}|dx$$
How do i solve it?

Comment: WA says this here $$\frac{1}{12} \pi ^2 (-12 \log (A)+1+\log (4)+\log (\pi ))$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that
$$\begin{align}
I&:=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+e^x}dx=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{-x}x\ln(x)}{1+e^{-x}}dx\\&=\int^{\infty}_{0}x\ln (x)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}e^{-kx}\,dx\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\int^{\infty}_{0}x\ln(x)e^{-kx}\,dx.
\end{align}$$
Moreover, after integrating by parts,
$$\begin{align}\int^{\infty}_{0}x\ln(x)e^{-kx}\,dx&=\frac{1}{k}\int^{\infty}_{0}(1+\ln(x))e^{-kx}\,dx\\&=\frac{1-\ln(k)}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^2}\int^{\infty}_{0}\ln(t)e^{-t}\,dt\\&=\frac{1-\ln(k)-\gamma}{k^2}.\end{align}$$
where $\gamma$ is the  [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals).
Hence,
$$\begin{align}
I&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1-\ln(k)-\gamma}{k^2}\\
&=( 1-\gamma)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}+\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k)}{k^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\left(1-\gamma+\ln(2)\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\left(12\ln(A)-\gamma-\ln(2\pi)\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\left(1+\ln(4\pi)-12 \log (A)\right)
\end{align}.$$
where $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant)t and  we used [Evaluating a sum $-\zeta'(2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084698/evaluating-a-sum-zeta2) .

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
I&=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right|_{s=2}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right|_{s=2}\big((1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)\big)
\end{align*}
Then use the result
$$\zeta'(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6(-12\ln A+\gamma+\ln(2\pi)),\quad\Gamma'(2)=1-\gamma$$